# Влияют ли sleep() или wait() в момент вызова, на флаг isInterrupted() или нет?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Если я приостанавливаю поток при помощи методов `sleep()` или `wait()`, флаг `isInterrupted()` в этот момент меняется или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Флаг не меняется, но если в момент `sleep` или `wait` вызвать метод `interrupt()`, то ожидание прервется и будет выброшено исключение `InterruptedException`.